# Python automated script file transferring

Tags: android, python

I am looking for a solution for copying all the files from a specific directory on the hard drive, to a specific or non specific directory on my android phone, once this device is connected.

I would like these files to be automatically moved (or at least copied) to my phone once I connect it to the computer and run the .py file.

I have windows 7 and python 2.7

I was trying this from another answer but I can't understand because there is few explanation, therefore I cannot get it to work.

**edit:** I have figured out how to transfer files between to folders but I want to my phone. So how can I fix the error of my system not finding the path of my phone, that'll fix my problem I believe. The code works fine the problem is the path.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import shutil
sourcePath = r'C:\Users\...\What_to_copy_to_phone'
destPath = r'Computer\XT1032\Internal storage'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourcePath):

#figure out where we're going
dest = destPath + root.replace(sourcePath, '')

#if we're in a directory that doesn't exist in the destination folder
#then create a new folder
if not os.path.isdir(dest):
    os.mkdir(dest)
    print 'Directory created at: ' + dest

#loop through all files in the directory
for f in files:

    #compute current (old) & new file locations
    oldLoc = root + '\\' + f
    newLoc = dest + '\\' + f

    if not os.path.isfile(newLoc):
        try:
            shutil.copy2(oldLoc, newLoc)
            print 'File ' + f + ' copied.'
        except IOError:
            print 'file "' + f + '" already exists'
```

I am sorry I am being handful but I thought I had solved it.

Comment: Ok, what's your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Eric Renouf  I edited my answer, this is what I am trying

Comment: Now, if copy part is working, then your question is automatically detect your phone usb connection with your Win7 PC?

Comment: The copy part is working but only for files between the win7 hard drives not for my phone which is what I want. Automatic detection of the phone is not a problem., I get an error: `The system cannot find the specified path`

Comment: Have you tried `adb push` to copy files into your android device ?

Comment: I don't know how to use `adb push`, besides I think I making a small error defining the phone path, it should work with `shutil` as well.

Comment: Android devices are connected to PC as MTP, Not as USB mass storage devices. You can verify this by `cd` from a command line prompt. You will get same error.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, there is no way to access your phone's internal memmory with a drive letter, because, Android connects as an MTP device, and not as a Mass Storage device. But, there are some weird solutions:

1. Root the phone and get a application which enables "Mass Storage" .
2. If you can not root and if(only if) both the computer are on the same network, run FTP server in you phone, and you get access for file copy by ftp.

But for you case I recommend [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)- `adb push C:\src /phone_destination` is the best solution.You can google and easily find out way to do this in python.

Comment: Well it is rooted, let me try what you posted, I don't wanna use FTP and such because the whole purpose of writing this script will be vain

Comment: I get compilation error invalid syntax pointing in the `adb push`.

Answer (score 1):

Google offers adb-sync, which is also available in python. This allows backup/synchronization of files on android device to PC.

The following github repo provides instructions on how to setup the process ie: enable USB Debugging, etc... however I suggest installing 15 second adb installer as opposed to downloading/installing the massive Android SDK just to get adb.

adb-sync: https://github.com/google/adb-sync
15 Sec ADB installer: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

Answer (score 0):

A little late to answer, but I use SSH certs and crontab to run a ping command against my local IP and pipe that to an scp recursive copy. It will copy any changes over. No issue yet, and it's been running 4 years straight. I can't for the life of me find the command line that's running.

Comment: Not really answering the question as OP asks for a python file transferring script between  folders.